# Count the number of variables in a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to reassemble some data that was loss for my office.  One thing that could make life exponentially better is the ability to count the number of variables in a formula.  For example:

```
=500+500+500
```

Ideally, I would like to return "3" in this situation, as there are three "variables" in the above formula.  Right now I'm using a formula to pull the exact value from the particular cell, but I'd like to add something that would allow me to also output the number of variables in the formula/calculation.

Comment: This question is very broad. What should `=500*1+500*1+500*1` return, 6? What is your definition of a "variable"?

Comment: Technically, yes, that's what I'm looking for.  Variable as in a bare number.  Each cell I have to do this with would only be "=#+#+#"

Comment: If the only operation is addition, then you could use `Split` in VBA to do this easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only operator is `+` then this will get the count:

```
=LEN(FORMULATEXT(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(A1),"+",""))+1
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since you may have different operators beside a `+` sign, you could do something like this in VBA:

```
Function count_parts(rngFormula As Range) As Integer

    'Create an array with all the operators you want to account for
    Dim operatorArray As Variant, operator As Variant
    operatorArray = Array("+", "-", "/", "*")

    'Capture the formula in the cell passed in
    Dim strFormIn As String: strFormIn = rngFormula.Formula
    Dim strFormOut As String: strFormOut = strFormIn

    'Loop through the operators in the array and swap them out
    'So the strFormOut is completely rid of them all
    For Each operator In operatorArray
        strFormOut = Replace(strFormOut, operator, "")
    Next

    'Count the difference in characters between our starting
    'formula and the formula without operators, subtracting 1.
    count_parts = Len(strFormIn) - Len(strFormOut) + 1
End Function
```

If `+` is the only operator you have to account for, then a much more simple function could be used:

```
Function count_parts(rngFormula As Range) As Integer
    count_parts = UBound(Split(rngFormula.Formula, "+")) + 1
End Function
```

You can stick either of these in a new module in your VBE and after saving the workbook you can use this formula in a cell like `=count_parts(A1)`

Comment: @BigBen Yep. That would make more sense. I have fixed it.

Comment: Good point. I'll scrap those since they arent really operators.